# Preg_replace with a query to database

Tags: php, preg-replace

I know "preg_replace" function but not how to use a query inside it. For instance I'm able to convert `__` into `<em>`:

`$text = preg_replace('/__(.+?)__/s', '<em>$1</em>', $text);`

I am looking for something more powerful. 
I would like to replace some pre-formatted text (i.e. `[TTT]112233[/TTT]`) into another text which is the result of a query (i.e. `echo "$text2";` ).

The variable $text2 is the result of a query like `"SELECT * FROM table WHERE id=112233"`;

Is there an embedded php function that do this? Many thanks, Fabio

Comment: The wording of the question isn't 100% clear, but I think you'd have to run the query, get the result(s) into a variable, loop through the rows (if there are more than one) and get the column(s) containing the result, and then run each column through your replace function.

Comment: Imagine this. I write a content and inside the content I want to display a quote. 
That quote is registered into a database and it has an ID = 112233.
So I would like to write into my content something like this:
"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
*[TTT]112233[/TTT]*
Ut enim ad minim veniam,

The result should be the text with the complete quote inside it.

I don't know the ID of the quote before reading the content-text.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this. Probably not the most efficient, but it's a way. It's based in [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php)

```
$line = preg_replace_callback(
        '|[TTT](\d+)[/TTT]|',
        function ($matches) use ($dbConnection) {
           $q = "SELECT textColumn FROM table WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
           $stmt = mysqli_prepare($dbConnection,$q);
           mysqli_bind_param("i",$matches[1]);
           mysqli_execute($stmt);
           mysqli_bind_result($result);              
           mysqli_fetch($stmt);
           return "[TTT]$result[/TTT]";
        },
        $line
    );
```

Note this assumes `mysqli` but your method may differ.